# DynamicReports stl.style().setFont(font)

Tags: java, fonts, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am trying to embed my font file into jar files, so my application can be executed with out any dependency of fonts in any platform.

The problems is that, when I want to set the font of *DynamicReports* columns, text components or ... by setting their style; the setFont method in style object need a *FontBuilder* object. and I only can change the *FontName*, *FontSize* and ... which is n't what i need. I am not sure, but I think it uses the Font name to create font object from installed font of OS.

Is there any way to set font of type *`java.awt.Font`* in *DynamicReports* or is there any other way keep my application independent of OS installed font.

If anyone can help me, I would be very happy.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for [ricardo](http://www.dynamicreports.org/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=70&sid=bf21df4da6339e8f141587ef6362bee3) the site admin of [DynamicReports](http://www.dynamicreports.org/) Forum, He answered the question as below:

You don't have to set java.awt font. What you need to do is to register a new font family name that will refer to font files that are located in the jar file.

See the following link on how to create a new font family:
http://www.dynamicreports.org/documentation/fonts

The following link shows how to use the new font:
http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/fontsreport